# Vector notation for $k>n$ vectors in $\Bbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation

I'm reading Advanced calculus of several variables by Edwards, C.Henry. On page 6, the author is proceeding with the proof that any $n+1$ vectors in $\Bbb{R^n}$ are linearly dependent and writes :

"Suppose that $v_1,...,v_k$ are $k>n$ vectors in $\Bbb{R^n}$ and write $$v_j = (a_{1j},...,a_{nj})$$

where $j=1,...,k$."

I have understood vectors of $\Bbb{R^n}$, as $n$-tuples of real numbers as in $(x_1, ... , x_n)$. What is the purpose of introducing row column notation to describe them? I think it might have something to do with the next part ;

"...We want to find real numbers $x_1,...,x_k$, not all zero, such that

$\bar0=x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 +  ... + x_kv_k$."

Afterwards this vector equation can be written as a system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations ; a non-trivial solution exists and the proof is complete.

Comment: it may just want to remind you the form of the elements in $\Bbb R ^n$ if the author did not uses $a_{1j},....,a_{nj}$ in the consequent content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the notation means row column vector. It's just a way to uniquely identify each real number. In other words, $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ is just the $i$-th entry of the $j$-th vector. This is useful because it easily lets you see the total number of unknowns.

If we have $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then this notation implies $i \in \mathbb{N}\cap [1, n]$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}\cap [1, k]$. Since in the proof we want to see how many equations vs unknowns we have, using this notation we can expand the equation $\vec{0} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i v_i$, and obtain $n$ equations of the form
$$
0 = x_1 a_{i 1} +  x_2 a_{i 2} + ... + x_k a_{i k} \quad  1\le i \le n
$$

but since $k>n$, here we see that indeed we have more unknowns (the $x_k$'s) than equations.